# Access denied by ACL in Oracle APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, acl, ora-24247

May be this is a common problems,but I have googled it and post it in some forums but I still didn't get the answer..

I have a problem with my ACL. I was following this tutorial http://dbtricks.com/?p=159 and everything works fine. But when I made REST web service in Oracle APEX 5.0 and tried to run the service, it gave me error:

> ORA-29273: HTTP request failed  ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
>   ORA-24247: network access denied
>   by access control list (ACL)

I have set the ACL for user APEX_050000.

If anyone has an idea about this, please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try configuring the ACL for the "default parsing schema" ID; generally the schema that owns the tables; not the APEX schema that contains the application.  That solved the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the ACL for the schema that owns the APEX application that you are trying to run.

Comment: yes.. I have done that also. I run the script from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/install.32/e13366/db_install.htm#HTMIG213 and the error changes:
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at &quot;SYS.UTL_HTTP&quot;, line 1369 ORA-29263: HTTP protocol error